# Adding Scrollbar to dropdown using php/html

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I am using php and MySQL to connect my form to a database for dropdown menu as the dropdown list is long, so I want to add a vertical scroll bar to the dropdown list. I have created the dropdown list using datalist tag of HTML5 and I have searched so much about but was not able to find anything that worked, I have already tried size and overflow. Here is my code

```
<div class="ltxtbox">Project Name: </div>
<div class="rtxtbox"> <input type="text" list="Project_Name" name='Project_Name' data-validation="required"  >
<?php mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); // Here database details
mysql_select_db('test1');

$sql = "SELECT Project_Name FROM dd";
$result = mysql_query($sql); // Running mysql query

echo "<datalist  id='Project_Name'>"; // Open your drop down box
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['Project_Name'] ."'>" . $row['Project_Name'] ."</option>";
        }   // Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
echo "</datalist>"; // Close your drop down box

?>
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've researched your question and found out that you can't do too much with datalist instead you can use select to do the same thing..

```
select {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

will do the trick and you can use overflow anyhow you want..

Comment: Yes I know but I can't use select as doesn't allow manual entry and dropdown both. If there is a way to allow manual entry in select than only I can use it. @abhishek

Comment: Actually the thing is there is a sort of bug in chrome if you run the same code of yours in mozzila it will works perfectly, let me know if stuck.

Comment: Yes it works fine in Internet Explorer and Mozilla. Thanks! @abhishek

Comment: Glad could help! but i will still recommend you the select tag you will find various js frameworks on internet. that can modify your select tag to use as datalist. @BhaveshGarg